# Reference introductory books or articles to Game Semantics

Tags: reference-request, semantics, game-theory

Where can I find *introductory* books, articles, notes or slides on Game Semantics?

I have searched a lot on the internet but I'm not satisfied by the material I found. It either is too informal, or it assumes too much knowledge of/attitude to other kind of semantics, and it's hard to follow for a beginner.

Ideally the material shouldn't have any prerequisites, except a little of game theory and few concepts of semantics.

Examples of the material that I've found are:

- [Notes on Game Semantics](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~curien/Game-semantics.pdf): These are quite good, but they lack a bit of formalism at the beginning and I find some explanations or examples difficult to follow.
- [Tutorial on Game Semantics](http://www.illc.uva.nl/lint/documents/workshop08/slides/abramsky_tutorial.pdf): Slides; they lack oral explanations.

Comment: We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there.

Comment: Have you seen Guy McCusker's [Marktoberdorf lecture notes](http://www.cs.bath.ac.uk/~gam23/papers/marktoberdorf.ps.gz)?

Comment: @Raphael I understand the dislike, but I don't see where else should I ask such a question. Surely not on TCS. Also, the meta question you linked has positive votes(which I think means there is an interest in dealing with these questions) but it has two answer, both downvoted, which I take as if there isn't any consensus on the matter at the moment. If you think that I could improve the question, then could you tell me what you think it currently lacks, or how would you write it?

Comment: @Bakuriu I understand your problem, but unfortunately "there is no other place" != "this is the right place". The usual way to approach literature research is by a) walking backward from current research articles, b) walking forward from seminal work and c) personal recommendation from experts. Neither works well on SE; in particular, c) is problematic because answers are unlikely to be objectively justified (but more along the lines of "I like X, it's good"). Unfortunately, among many similar questions (several closed by now) now good strategy to deal with questions such as yours has emerged.

Comment: @Raphael The OP asked for introductions to a subject that require at most certain background (."*little of game theory and few concepts of semantics*"); the question is possible to answer objectively, in my opinion (I have posted an answer, see below).

Answer (score 2):

I know three introductions that may satisfy your criteria. All of them will use some Category Theory, but the first one (by Jürjens)  is actually quite light on that side -- he actually defines what categories and morphisms are in the context of game semantics, on page 111 (11th page of the article). You may want to read this one first, and then the others.

- [Games in the Semantics of Programming Languages -- an elementary introduction](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1020883810034) by Jan Jürjens.
- [Game Semantics](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/articles/abramsky-mccusker-game-semantics.pdf) by Abramsky and McCusker.
- [Semantics of Interaction](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0121) (`arXiv:1312.0121v1 [cs.LO]`) by Abramsky.